# Django: Reasonable to store session data in Class Variable?

Tags: python, django, class

I have a class which parses multiple urls/feeds
and stores hashes of entries. Formerly I had put the hashes into a session variable,
but instead of hitting the db I now switched to a class variable in the form of {request.user.id : [hashes]}. Is this bad practice? Any reasons against it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a lot of reasons not to do it.

I'm sure caching solutions offer robust solutions to memory management.  This includes running as a daemon.  Having cache invalidation, setting lifetimes on the data.

By setting a classvariable, you are forgoing the above things.

Additionally, caching solutions provide a clean documented, api for interfacing with them.

Comment: Also, what happens when the app is recycled and memory is trashed. How are the hash entries persisted?

Comment: Thanks. I'm using memcache to store the actual rendered entries. The hashtable is only relevant for the AJAX-update cycle, so it doesn't really need to persist. But I will think about an implementation via memcache.